# How to pass variable to a do block with sqlx?

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

I am trying to run the following `do` block script in sql through `sqlx`. As `do` block doesn't accept parameters, I tried to prepare it beforehand.

```golang
func LinkSessionUser(sessionId string, userId string, result *bool) error  {
    db := database.GetDB()
    statement, err := db.Preparex(`
        do
        $$
        begin
        if (exists(select id from "session" where id = $1) and exists(select id from "user" where id = $2)) then
          return insert into "session_user" (session_id, user_id) values ($1, $2) on conflict do nothing;
        else
          raise exception "Either session(id=%) or user(id=%) doesn't exist" $1, $2;
        end if;
        end
        $$;
    `)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return statement.Get(result, sessionId, userId)
}
```

But as I run it, I got the following errors:

```
sql: expected 0 arguments, got 2
```

How can I fix this issue? Should I be using `Preparex` to replace `prepare` in sql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"Should I be using Preparex to replace prepare in sql?"* -- Yes, however the problem you've encountered has nothing to do with `Preparex`, or the `Go` language itself, for that matter.

The *code* block of the `DO` command is a `string literal`, this string literal will not be, and has no reason to be, parsed during the `PREPARE` command execution, which is why the resulting prepared statement will have *no* defined parameters. As you correctly point out, `DO` does not support input parameters, but trying to get around that limitation by wrapping `DO` in a prepared statement will simply not produce the result you were hoping for.

If you need to *conditionally execute parameterized SQL statements* then you should use the `CREATE FUNCTION` command and explicitly execute the resulting function.